# Why is -bash: PATH: command not found displayed when I open my terminal window?

Tags: osx-lion, epd-python

I installed EPD Free 7.3.2 and it was running fine until I wanted to modify PATH to point to where my Python scripts are. I gave up on that and reverted back to my original .bash_profile file.

```
# Setting PATH for EPD_free-7.3-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

When launching terminal, I get this:

```
Last login: Thu Jan  3 08:50:20 on ttys000
-bash: PATH: command not found
```

However, I am able to run iPython and all the libs that come with EPD w/o problems. Anybody knows what the problem is with "PATH: command not found"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spaces around the `=` are a problem. Use this assignment:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the spaces around `=`:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
```

Otherwise you're trying to run the (non-existent) command `PATH` with `=` and `"/Library..."` as its arguments.